# Create Sales Order Payment in 2020R2

Tags: acumatica

I'm upgrading a customization that was able to create payments on Sales Orders via code. Prior to 2020R2 I could use something along the lines of...

```
PXGraph graph;
orderEntry.CreatePaymentProc(orderEntry.Document.Current, out graph);
ARPaymentEntry paymentEntry = (ARPaymentEntry)graph;
ARPayment payment = paymentEntry.Document.Select();

payment.PaymentMethodID = ...;
payment.CuryOrigDocAmt = ...;
payment.ExtRefNbr = ...;
payment.CashAccountID = ...;

paymentEntry.Document.Update(payment);
paymentEntry.Actions.PressSave();
```

As of Acumatica 2020R2 `CreatePaymentProc` is no longer a method of `SOOrderEntry`.

How can the same result be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The full solution here involved a couple additional method calls...

```
SOOrder order = orderEntry.Document.Current;
CreatePaymentExt createPaymentExt = orderEntry.GetExtension<CreatePaymentExt>();
SOQuickPayment payment = createPaymentExt.QuickPayment.Current;
createPaymentExt.SetDefaultValues(payment, order);

payment.PaymentMethodID = ...;
payment.CuryOrigDocAmt = ...;
payment.ExtRefNbr = ...;
payment.CashAccountID = ...;

ARPaymentEntry paymentEntry = createPaymentExt.CreatePayment(payment, order, ARPaymentType.Payment);
paymentEntry.Save.Press();
```

Answer (score 2):

All of the methods and actions for the payment creating for the Sales Orders records in the **Acumatica 2020R2** release you can find in the extension `CreatePaymentExt`class.

As of **Acumatica 2020R2** `CreatePaymentProc` has been changed the `CreatePayment` method on the `CreatePaymentExt` class.